# Java call Groovy class directly exception: Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

Tags: java, groovy

When I try to call a Groovy class in Java, I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   groovy/runtime/metaclass/java/lang/StringMetaClass, method:
>   super$2$invokeMethod signature:
>   (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;)
>   Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

here is Groovy code snippet

```
class TestGroovy{
    def testSplit(){
        def orglist = "01,02,03"
        println orglist.split(",")
    }
}
```

and this is the Java code snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     TestGroovy tg = new TestGroovy(); 
     tg.testSplit();
}
```

Can anyone shine some light on this issue?
Thanks in advance!

---

I set up a MCVE, but I did not reproduce the issue this time. It works as expected.

Here is the steps of MCVE to set up a Java call Groovy class

1. Installation of the Groovy tools for the Eclipse IDE

I am using Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0)

Open the Eclipse Update manager via the Help ▸ Install New Software…​ menu entry to install the Groovy Eclipse plug-in. Enter the following URL in this dialog:

http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.6

Select: Groovy-Eclipse(Required) and click next to install the Groovy plugin.

2.Create a new Groovy project called CroovyCalledByJava
 File ▸ New ▸ Other ▸ Groovy ▸ Groovy Project

3.Create a new Groovy class called TestGroovy via  File ▸ New ▸ Other ▸ Groovy ▸ Groovy Class

```
package product.rule 
class TestGroovy {
def testSplit(){
    def orglist = "01,02,03"
    println orglist.split(",")
}
```

}

4. Create a new Maven project Called JavaCallGroovy via File ▸ New ▸ Other ▸ Maven ▸ Maven Project

Add the following dependency to the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

5. Config the Java Build Path via Right-click your project, select "Properties" and check that the build path includes the CroovyCalledByJava project
6. Edit the generated App.java

   ```
   import product.rule.TestGroovy;
   public class App 
   {
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
       TestGroovy tg = new TestGroovy(); 
       tg.testSplit();
   }
   }
   ```
7. Run APP and Java application

Comment: Are you running into this - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004967

Comment: Thank you @Rao. It seems that it is not the same issue.

Comment: What is your java and groovy versions? Are you running from any IDE?

Comment: Groovy 2.4.11 

java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0)

Comment: What kind of setup have you put in place to allow mixing Groovy & Java under the same project ("joint compilation")? Gradle ? Maven+GMaven? Something else? (maybe nothing, maybe Eclipse does this alone nowadays?). Or is it a multi-project build? Can you reproduce this with a [mcve]? (⬅ not trying to be pedantic, it's how "mcve" is expanded)

Comment: I set up a MCVE, but I did not reproduce the issue this time. It works as expected. It is odd. Anyway, thank you all for your help! 
I am going to add the MCVE steps to my question.